# Django add new line (break line) to display list of some foreign key

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, format

This is what i have done so far to break a line:

```
class CreatePost(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=99)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=9000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="user_post")
    def __str__(self):
        return format_html('SUBJECT : {} <br/>  DESCRIPTION : {}  <br/> Email : {} <br/>', (self.subject, self.desc, self.user.username))
```

for admin.py

```
class CreatePostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'subject', 'desc')
    class Meta:
        model = models.CreatePost

class RespondToPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'post', 'to', 'content')
    class Meta:
        model = models.RespondToPost
```

I am dealing with `RespondToPostAdmin` and i am getting error regarding the formatting in string dunder method:

```
Exception Type: IndexError
Exception Value:    
Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

i am not sure why, any help is appreciated, if there is better solution to format my string dunder method to add breaklines/new lines, please suggest me

edit:
admin model is not listening to the format method:

```
class RespondToPostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'format_post', 'to', 'content')
    class Meta:
        model = models.RespondToPost
    def format_post(self,obj):
        return 'SUBJECT :{}  %s <br/> DESCRIPTION : {} %s  <br/> Email : {} %s <br/> '.format(obj.post.subject, obj.post.desc, obj.post.user.username)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra brackets around arguments.

```py
def __str__(self):
    return format_html('SUBJECT : {} <br/>  DESCRIPTION : {}  <br/> Email : {} <br/>', self.subject, self.desc, self.user.username)
```

EDIT: you are mixing multiple things together...

```py
class CreatePost(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=99)
    desc = models.TextField(max_length=9000)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_post")

    def __str__(self):
        return format_html(
            "SUBJECT : {} <br/>  DESCRIPTION : {}  <br/> Email : {} <br/>", self.subject, self.desc, self.user.username
        )


@admin.register(CreatePost)
class CreatePostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("__str__", "format_post")

    def format_post(self, obj):
        return mark_safe(
            "SUBJECT :{} <br/> DESCRIPTION : {}  <br/> Email : {} <br/> ".format(
                obj.subject,
                obj.desc,
                obj.user.username,
            )
        )
```

will show [image]

You can use "**str**" from model as item in `list_display` or `format_post` method as you created. `format_html` is preferred over `mark_safe`. [Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.format_html) about it.

Comment: that did not add any new line/break any line.

Comment: It works only in html for example in django admin. You can show it admin for example just like this `list_display = ["__str__"]`. Just test it and works fine.

Comment: I am doing that in admin panel, and it seem that it is not recognizing the format method

Comment: I updated my post, look at the last code block

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am using `createpost` as a foreign key for another admin model

Comment: won't help you. Don't know what you're trying to do but you should already know how to break line ;)